# How to establish a TCP connection given a host name and port on Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

On WP 7.1 the Socket class is missing methods like Socket.Connect(string, int) that would make this straight-forward. The available alternative Socket.ConnectAsync apparently needs a numerical IP address (passed with the SocketAsyncEventArgs object).

Moreover, methods like Dns.GetHostEntry are also missing, so you cannot easily get an IP address given a host name.

Comment: Use the Socket.Connect(hostname, port) overload.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Socket.Connect is not available on WP7.1.

Comment: Don't call us, we'll call you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that???

Comment: @Andreas Huber - "Don't bother to pursue your application further." (http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/dont-call-us.html)

Comment: @IDWMaster: Yes, I was aware of the meaning in general, just not what Hans Passant means in this particular context. I can think of two possible meanings but neither makes much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that connecting to a host with a given host name is actually quite easy. Contrary to what the questions suggests, SocketAsyncEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint can be assigned either an IPEndPoint or a DnsEndPoint object:

```
var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
args.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(hostName, port);
args.Completed += ... // Add your completion handler here
Socket.ConnectAsync(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many calls not available in the Windows Phone Mango API, in particular Sockets are always async (as a consequence there is no NetworkStream) and there is no support for serversockets.
That said, there is a nice tutorial for using sockets in mango here. A little tic tac toe example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

And there is a bit of documentation on using sockets here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202870(v=vs.92).aspx